# PHP - Get only one element with MySQL

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

I use PHP and MySQL in order to access to my database.

My table is like this :

```
Table(id INT PK, title VARCHAR(255))
```

I'm using PDO and I'd like to get only the id :

```
SELECT id FROM Table WHERE title='stackover';
```

But PDO returns an array.

Comment: `$title = $array[0];

Comment: You can try something like :

$id = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM Table LIMIT 1"),0);

As long as you are sure you a) only want one result and b) you only ever expect to get one result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$statement->fetchColumn()` to get the id as `$id`.